# select 10 rows joined with all rows from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables `post` and `comments` and I want to select 10 posts joined with all comments:

```sql
 SELECT * from post p left join comments c on p.id = c.post LIMIT 10;
```

this query will not work since the limit is for post with comments and not for the posts alone. How can I do this then? Is it possible without using inner query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT P.*,C.* 
From (SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 0,10) AS P
             Left Join comments C ON C.Id = P.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward solution would be to separate a little:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 10) p
  ON p.id = c.post;
```

Comment: So it's not possible without inner query?

Comment: @jcubic You could aggregate all comments into one field using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. That would result in just one row per post with all the comments in a single field. Then you could use `LIMIT` on that without an inner query.